# Force repaint during Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html

I want to force a repaint during a Javascript loop. For example:

```
var s = document.getElementById("foo");
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    s.innerText = i + " times";
```

That updates at the end, but I would like to observe each intermediate step. The common response to this problem is to use `setTimeout`, however, there are three reasons that is unacceptable:

- There are other buttons/links etc on the page, and it is important that none of these can be clicked while the loop operates.
- At the end of the loop I want to display a popup, if the timeout fires then standard popup blockers will hide it, as it is no longer initiated by the user.
- If the user clicks while the loop is running, I want that click to be buffered until the loop completes, not fired half way through the loop.

Is there a way to force the browser to repaint?

Comment: > At the end of the loop I want to display a popup, if the timeout fires then standard popup blockers will hide it, as it is no longer initiated by the user. 
I'm not quite sure of this. I'm never using settimeout to window.open popups but almost each time the browser stops the popup

Comment: If the popup is opened in direct response to a user action (i.e. a click) then it's usually allowed. If you start it in response to something else, then often disallowed.

Comment: *"Is there a way to force the browser to repaint?"* I don't believe so. Your first and third issues with `setTimeout` would seem to be  solvable. Not sure about the second.

Comment: @amnotiam The first I can see a solution to (it's in my control), the third isn't really solvable - I'd have to capture and "replay" all clicks etc.

Comment: @NeilMitchell: You could make your handlers to be aware of the asynchronous loop, and give your loop code the ability to register event handlers provided by the other handlers that were clicked during the loop, and then invoke them when the looping is complete.

Comment: just create a flag `isRunning`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is your only solution though, since the non-repaintable-in-the-middle is something important as a predicate for speed gains in rendering of browsers.

Perhaps could you manage a buffer-me flag in those click events you don't want to fire? Or better said a dont-buffer-me flag...

I hope it helped, best regards.